# Why This Works on HTTP but not in HTTPClient?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new to programming. So, I have an API service which has get method sending data in JSON like this

```
{ "records" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "aa"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "bb"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get data to my project using angular CLI. Here is inside every File

```
//name.ts
export interface Name {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

//name.service.ts
...
constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getName(): Observable<Name[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._url).pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
}
...

//app.component.ts
...
names: Name[];

constructor(private _nameService: nameService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._nameService.getName().subscribe(data => this.names = data['records']);
}
```

This is working fine. But, if I'm using HttpClient module, and change `getName()` function inside `name.service.ts` to this:

```
//name.service.ts after getName() change
...
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

getName(): Observable<Name[]> {
    return this._http.get<Name[]>(this._url);
}
...
```

Suddenly I got empty list. What did I do wrong? Should I get rid of `<Name[]>` so it became `return this._http.get(this._url);`? But, it would raise an error and can't be compiled.

Comment: use `return this._http.get<any>(this._url);` or create an interface to cope with the `records` part of the data return

Comment: Check with angular version.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**service**

```
getName(): Observable<Name[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._url).pipe(map((res: any) => res['records']));
}
```

**component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._nameService.getName().subscribe(data => this.names = data);
}
```